# Getting array size in a JsonConverter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

If I'm running a json converter similar to the very rough code below is it possible to get the size of the array without moving the reader on from its starting position? Or can I reset its position or clone the reader?

```
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var jArray = JArray.Load(reader);
            int arrayLength = jArray.Count;
            return reader.Value;
        }
```

Update - I've added a contrived example below if this code is run you'll see that although Role is marked with JsonRequired it doesn't fail validation due to the reader moving past that value in the reader. Would the depth property of the reader give me what I need possibly?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{
                'Email': 'james@example.com',
                'Active': true,
                'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
                'Roles': [
                    {   
                        'Access': 'Write'
                    }
                 ]
            }";
            Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
        }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomMaximumListLengthConverter), 1)]
        public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Role
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string Access { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomMaximumListLengthConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        private readonly int _maxLength;

        public CustomMaximumListLengthConverter(int maxLength)
        {
            _maxLength = maxLength;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

            var obj = JArray.Load(reader);
            if(obj.Count > _maxLength)
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Too many items");
            }
            return reader.Value;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I will add that I know I can validate the model using ValidationContext etc but I don't want to do that.

Also, I've realised that reader.Value returns null where I think I want to return an IList although that throws a deserialization error.

EDIT 2

After playing around it seems the below gives me basically what I'm after in a rough and ready way. Is there a better approach?

```
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var obj = JArray.Load(reader);
            if (obj.Count > _maxLength)
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Too many items");
            }
            return obj.ToObject(objectType);
        }
```

Comment: *is it possible to get the size of the array without moving the reader on from its starting position?* -- no, the [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) does not have an array count at the beginning of the array, so it's necessary to load it just to count it.  *Or can I reset its position or clone the reader?* [`JsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) is forward only so you can't reset it.

Comment: But `JToken` has a [`CreateReader()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_CreateReader.htm) method, is that what you need? You haven't really explained your problem so I don't know whether that would solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm using this code in web api on a customconverter. I want to validate (within the json) that a list only has a maximum of x items. So when I run the above code I get the array count but it's skipped past all the children, therefore their validation is also skipped. So I was wondering can I clone the reader and do a read without moving the original reader on. Does that make sense?

Comment: `JsonTextReader` is documented to be forward-only and can't be rewound.  Are you purely validating the JSON, or also deserializing at the same time?  If deserializing, can you provide a full [mcve] of what you are trying to do?

Comment: My only concern is to get the number of elements of the JSON array. I don't particularly want to deserialize but that occurs due to using Jarray.

Comment: Then if you could share a full [mcve] showing what you are doing, we might be able to suggest alternative implementations.  As mentioned previously there's no way to rewind a `JsonReader`

Comment: Hi, added code solution.

Comment: Hi, I asked this question a bit ago and never got a solution and couldn't work it out unfortunately. I added the code solution into the first post. Basically I can get the array size but due to the forward nature of the JsonReader when I get the size I cannot validate the role object. Can you clone the JsonReader somehow?

Comment: *Basically I can get the array size but due to the forward nature of the JsonReader when I get the size I cannot validate the role object.* then please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  There's nothing shown in your question about validating a "role object".  *Can you clone the JsonReader somehow?* -- you cannot clone a `JsonReader`.  But if you provide the requested [mcve] we may be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: The minimum reproducible example is in the first post along with the request to validate the role object. RoleName is marked with JsonRequired.

Comment: I'm getting a *Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property 'RoleName' not found in JSON. Path '[0]', line 3, position 5.* using your current code, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/cliTEd